# Scrum Template Upgrades?

Tags: tfs

When you upgrade your tfs server does it automatically update the scrum template your using for existing projects or do you have to do that manually? If manually what is involved?

The team project we are working on was defined in 2012 RTM but our server is now @ 2013.3. We haven't used the work items that much at this point (at little bit initially for a pilot project) but we are to push harder for our organization to use scrum so we want to make sure we are on the latest/greatest template before we start.

Answer (score 2):

Your process template is not automatically updated. As long as you haven't made any changes to the original process template, upgrading is quite easy.

You enable new features by running the [Configure Features Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff432837.aspx) in your team projects configuration page.

If the automatic update fails, you will get a message describing the errors it encountered. Now you will have to apply those updates manually which is also described on MSDN but is a bit harder.

A not so nice but easy way is to remove all work items and process data from your project and then add the newest items. [Martin Hinshelwood has some great guidance](http://nakedalm.com/do-you-know-how-to-upgrade-a-process-template-but-still-keep-your-data-intact/) on how to do this.

Comment: thanks for the help. So after i run the "Configure Feature wizard" above i will be using scrum template 2013.3? I tried to find out a way to verify which template you are using and, as far as i could tell, there isn't a way. I did run the configure feature wizard an it finished successfully.

Comment: The Team Project Manager (http://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com/) is a great tool to inspect and edit your process template. It will show you which version you're using.

Comment: No, after running the 'configure wizard' you will have your old template enabled with the new features between versions. You can just download the 2013.3 work items, re-add any customizations, and overwrite your existing template to make it the 2013.3 one.